# Are joke comments not wanted?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-comments

I posted a comment on this question yesterday: [Are self-sealing stem bolts a Star Trek in-joke?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/240438/are-self-sealing-stem-bolts-a-star-trek-in-joke)

It was meant as a joke, and I don't think it was offensive. The last I looked, it had about 20 upvotes. I think it's been deleted, which I'm a little sad about, as I thought it was fun.

It wasn't super-informative in terms of the question, although it did mention [a fictional Star Trek component](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Heisenberg_compensator) which *is* something of an in-joke, so it wasn't entirely off-topic.

Are joke comments not wanted?

Comment: Although I usually go for "humour with a point," many of my most highly-voted comments could be considered jokes.  Considering I have a comment that's received more votes than my most highly-voted post, I'd hate to lose it because one or two people don't have a sense of humour. :)

Comment: A whole bunch of my 'funny' comments get deleted. I try not to let it bug me. Per my own comment from a few years back; "*I favour a stricter interpretation of the rule. Feel free to post jokey comments but don't get bent out of shape if a friendly moderator comes along and sweeps them away.*"

Comment: As a rule of thumb, don't too get attached to *any* comments you post. They're considered ephemera and may be deleted at any time if a moderator feels that they're not contributing. Depending on the contents, it may be appropriate to write an answer or post in chat instead, if you want the content to stick around for longer.

Comment: As for "most highly-voted comments", see also https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2113/4918 "How can I find the most upvoted comment(s) on a site?" in case you want to judge them yourselves.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nine comment flags were raised on that question last night. I went through the comments this morning and deleted a bunch of them which were straying into extended only-tangentially-relevant discussion (various IRL examples, continuing on from [Barmar's comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/240438/are-self-sealing-stem-bolts-a-star-trek-in-joke#comment660339_240438)). I declined a couple of the comment flags, including the one on Barmar's comment since it gives some useful/interesting information, although the follow-up comments got too many to keep them all.

Your comment was one of those flagged, and I almost declined that flag too - certainly I wouldn't have deleted that 24-upvoted comment if I'd just happened across it while browsing. But *since it was flagged*, and didn't add anything useful except a bit of humour (and I didn't find it funny), I went ahead and deleted it.

But it's not doing much harm, I was on the fence about it, and usually I do leave much-upvoted joke comments alone rather than deleting them. Since it was considered worth a whole meta post, I've now undeleted it.

For the general principle on joke comments, see [What should we do about "funny" comments?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6576/31394) Personally I often use the number of comment upvotes as an indicator of humour value in lieu of "usefulness". If there's several jokes cluttering up a comments section and none of them got upvoted much, I might clear them up, especially if they're flagged. If there's one joke comment with a lot of upvotes, I'll usually assume the community likes it and leave it alone.

Comment: “Since it was considered worth a whole meta post” — I mean, only by me, and I'm a weirdo. I can totally see that it's a fine line, and that comments aren't really designed for jokes. Thanks for the link to that question, it's just what I was looking for and failed to find. (Can I tag it with deleted-comments, as it discusses deletion?)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Hmm, it's not technically about *deleted* comments, rather than about the possibility of deleting comments. I wonder if that tag should be renamed `comment-deletion`?

Comment: Yeah could be a good shout. "deleted-comments" could be for questions about specific comments that got deleted (if more thin-skinned divas like me is something we want a tag for on meta), and "comment-deletion" for the general concept?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Actually there's a [hell](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7039/31394) [of](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3056/31394) [a](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1327/31394) [lot](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7823/31394) [of](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5289/31394) [meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6470/31394) [posts](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12497/31394) [which](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2916/31394) are about deleted comments but don't have the tag ...